# Why does python produce a "memory error" error when calculating x > 1x10^8 primes

Tags: python, vb.net, python-2.7, memory-management

I have used vb.net to make the equivalent program to this python one

```
from colorama import init , Fore


init ( autoreset = True, convert = True)

first = 0
second = 1

print(first)
print(second)

def primes ( temp ) :

    for loopcount in range ( 2 , temp ) :
        if (temp % loopcount) == 0 :
            return False

    return True


while True :
    temp = first + second
    first = second
    second = temp

    if primes ( temp ) == True :
        print(Fore.RED + str(temp))

    else :
       print(temp)

    raw_input("")
```

and i found that vb.net could do greater than 1x10^300 whereas python can't keep up with anything beyond 1.02x10^8. I don't understand why as I thought that python was great with numbers and number crunching.

FYI: Colorama is the cross platform python library for allowing the colouring of text in the console

Comment: The code you posted seems a bit messed up? The primes function does not take in anything, but there's temp in the loop.

Comment: I guess what might happened is that you are using the range function with the temp variable to be too high. The range function creates a list with that many variables ( from 2 to temp). Try xrange! which is an iterator.

Comment: @user1157751 In python 3, `range` is an iterator and there is no `xrange`. The code uses `print()` which suggests python 3.

Comment: That worked but now when i reach 267914296, and I press enter again, the program takes about a minute for the next one to appear. It was pretty much instantaneous responses up until then but... my poor, poor computer. I'm having it's memorial service next week. ;) But seriously, I don't understand why it's taking so long when it is instantaneous prior to that number

Comment: @tdelaney, I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Can we see the VB program? If it really uses the same algorithm as the Python version, I'd expect it to take about 10^280 years to run, assuming you can do a million calculations a nanosecond.

Comment: I am curious how long does it take you to generate a list of 1*10^300 primes?

Comment: In vb.net, I take a slightly different approach. My friend in the class has made an optimised version of it... oh wait! That was without the prime calculator.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Y8qkafYk

Comment: Consider using python 3 unless you are specifically restricted to 2. But if you stick with 2, use `xrange`.

Comment: FWIW, you can see the list of known (and probable) prime Fibonacci numbers on OEIS: [A005478](https://oeis.org/A005478). Also see Wikipedia [Fibonacci prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_prime), in particular: "Except for the case n = 4, all Fibonacci primes have a prime index, because if a divides b, then F_a also divides F_b, but not every prime is the index of a Fibonacci prime".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program crashes because you used `range` when you wanted [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange).

Quoting the doc:

> This function is very similar to range(), but returns an xrange object instead of a list. This is an opaque sequence type which yields the same values as the corresponding list, without actually storing them all simultaneously. The advantage of xrange() over range() [occurs when] a very large range is used on a memory-starved machine

Try this instead:

```
for loopcount in xrange ( 2 , temp ) :
```